# sudo environment variables disappeared

Tags: sudo, environment-variables, visudo

Symptom:

```
user1@ubuntu:~$ printenv PATH
/system/company/root/bin:/usr/lib/icecc/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/system/company/scripts:/opt/puppetlabs/bin
user1@ubuntu:~$ sudo su - user2
[sudo] password for user1: 
user2@ubuntu:~$ printenv PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/opt/puppetlabs/bin
```

file /etc/environment:

```
PATH="/system/company/root/bin:/usr/lib/icecc/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/system/company/scripts"
COMPANY_ROOT="/system/company/root"
COMPANY_SCRIPTS_ROOT="/system/company/scripts"
```

visudo:

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        env_keep += "PATH"
Defaults        env_keep += "COMPANY_ROOT"
Defaults        env_keep += "COMPANY_SCRIPTS_ROOT"
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

~/.profile:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Additional check:

```
user1@ubuntu:~$ echo $COMPANY_ROOT
/system/COMPANY/root
user1@ubuntu:~$ sudo bash -c 'echo $COMPANY_ROOT'
[sudo] password for user1: 
/system/COMPANY/root
```

Why environment variables disappear right after sudo? I already set env_keep on visudo and /etc/environment file still not go.

Comment: Is `COMPANY_ROOT` in the environment already? Whats the output of `echo $COMPANY_ROOT; sudo bash -c 'echo $COMPANY_ROOT'`?

Comment: Running on what user? User1 or user2?

Comment: Do you have anything set in `~/.profile`? In Debian, I have also had global startup scripts overwrite paths.

Comment: Also, are either of those paths soft linked?

Comment: added ~/.profile content; What's soft link mean? it's variable.